# Angular 6 Async-await not working on http request

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, angular6, angular-promise

Hi im using angular 6 to call a rest api with the code below. I am trying to acheive making the code synchronous with the async-await function. however something is missing

```
async save() {

    if (this.changedRecords.length !== 0) {
          this.post('/api/devices/update-devices', this.changedRecords).
          then(x => { console.log("change"); console.log(`Resolved: ${x}`) });
    }
    if (this.newRecords.length !== 0) {
          this.post('/api/devices/new-devices', this.newRecords).
            then(x => { console.log("new"); console.log(`Resolved: ${x}`) });
    }
    if (this.deletedRecords != null) {
      this.post('/api/devices/delete-devices', this.deletedRecords).
        then(x => { console.log("deleted"); console.log(`Resolved: ${x}`) });
    }

}

  async post(url: string, list: DboDevice[]) {
    var result;
    if (list.length !== 0) {
      await this.http.post(url, list).subscribe(result => {
        result = true;
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
        result = false;
      });
    }
    else {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

However when I run this code, the values return as "Resolved: undefined" in the console. This leads me to beleive the await is not stopping the program in the post() function. What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular's `this.http.post` returns an RxJS Observable. Then calling `this.http.post(...).subscribe(...)` returns RxJS `Subscription` object. So none of them return Promise so you can't use them with `await`.

If you want to be able to use `await` with Observables you have to use `toPromise()` instead of `subscribe()` that returns a Promise that is resolved with the first value emitted by that Observable (it internally calles `subscribe` for you and wraps it with a `Promise` object).

```
await this.http.post(...).toPromise(value => {
  ...
});
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L342-L354

Comment: thanks martin very helpful information. this did end up being the problem, and I got it to work now.

Comment: Also for anybody who also comes across the problem of trying to output the error after this, I got it to work by adding 

.catch(error => { console.log(error) });

on the end of toPromise()